# Error pushing cloned repository

Tags: git, github, repository, clone

I'm new to git, and running into a problem trying to push a cloned repository onto my online repository.  I created a local repository as follows:

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"
git config --global user.email myemail
mkdir trash
cd trash
git init
touch test # Creates a file in git bash
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/trash.git
git push -u origin master
```

Then cloned a desired repository

```
git clone git@github.com:user/folder.git # Folder appears in my local repository
```

Then I push it to my project:

```
git add -A
git push -u origin master
```

Which prints: "Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.  Everything up-to-date."

However, this has not added my newly cloned repository onto my online repository.  What am I missing?  Thanks,

Mike

EDIT:

Thanks for your inputs -- my issue was that I was having trouble getting another person's repository both on my local and online repository (I couldn't figure out how to clone it to my local repository and then push it online).  Here is what I found as a solution:
-   Go to https://github.com/user/project
-   Click on “Fork” in the upper right hand corner of the page.

Copy (“clone”) your online repository onto your local machine:

```
 # Set up git

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email your.email

# Clone your project from online to your local repository

cd desiered/directory
git clone git@github.com:username/project.git
```

Comment: If I understand what you want to do then you are not understanding git correctly. Git repositories can't be "integrated" like this. I'd suggest reading more on Git. "Pro Git" is a good free online book.

Comment: I don't need to integrate the repositories, I just want to have an online repository that I have cloned -- what is the best way to get a cloned repository online?

Comment: The first part about `trash` is confusing. What `trash` has to do with folder? You have cloned `folder` from an online source and now you want it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a commit there in between add -A and push:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'foo'
git push -u origin master
```

or you can do

```
git commit -am 'foo'
git push -u origin master
```